# How do I add icons to the hicolor icon theme manually?

Tags: ubuntu, icons, themes

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 32-bit.

## My problem:

I'm trying to *manually* add an icon to hicolor (default) icon theme.

The only icon I have a 32x32 version of this icon.

I've tried going about this by simply adding a `.png` file in the `/usr/share/icons/hicolor/32x32/apps/` folder.

But, when I try to reference that icon in a `.desktop` file, like so:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Type=Application
Name=Some App
Name[en_US]=Some App
Icon=icon-name
Exec=app-executable
Comment[en_US]=Description.
```

The `.desktop`'s icon just shows up blank.

I have logged out and rebooted several times.

What do I do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your case do you need to update the icon cache of the *hicolor* theme with the following command:

```
sudo gtk-update-icon-cache -f /usr/share/icons/hicolor/
```

But you can add icons (to the *hicolor* theme) without touching system files adding your icon to `$HOME/.local/share/icons/hicolor/32x32/apps`, and thus is not necessary to update the icon cache to take effect, just stop the file manager (Nautilus) with:

```
nautilus -q
```

And launch it again